# Astronaut teaches aztec-like race to embrace technology

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for the author and title of a sci-fi short story along the following lines:

An astronaut crashes on a planet where technology is shunned. He is appointed king of the people in order for them to obey him and advance technology, only to find out that his successor must rip out his heart.

Some of the above may be a bit blurry as I read the story more than 30 years ago.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Even though the word astronaut was coined long before the space race, it always seems a very specific term to me, almost as specific as cosmonaut.  A space traveler from Earth who crashes on an inhabited planet in another star system is probably in the distant future and so not very likely to be an employee of the United States of America National Aeronautics and Space Administration.

Comment: This rings a vague bell. Is it one of those situations where he reigns for a year and is sacrificed at the end of the year? Also are wheels banned, and he gets around it by using [Reuleaux triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle) as wheels?

Comment: Ah, no, the Reuleaux triangles are in the Van Rijn story [The Three-Cornered Wheel](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55407), which is vaguely similar to your description but doesn't have anything about being king for a year.

Answer (score 8):

You didn't specify the exact age of the story, but being it was at least 30 years ago your description has some points in common with the 1967 Edmund Cooper novel [A Far Sunset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Far_Sunset). Also at [Fantastic Fiction](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/c/edmund-cooper/far-sunset.htm)

Points that match:

1. An astronaut crashes on a planet where technology is shunned.

> Partial Check.  The starship Gloria mundi, built and manned by the United States of Europe, lands on the planet Altair Five in the year 2032. Most of the crew mysteriously disappears soon after touchdown, leaving only the psychiatrist Paul Marlow, the book's protagonist.

He is appointed king of the people

> Check.  A central theme in the novel is the clash between Marlowe's rational worldview and the natives' superstitious and often brutal culture. Paul Marlow (pronounced Poul Mer Lo by the Bayani tribe he lives amongst) gains a leading position in the primitive society.

in order for them to obey him and advance technology,

> He uses that power to educate the alien race, enabling them to make inventions that improve their society, such as the wheel, the ball-bearing and the axle.

only to find out that his successor must rip out his heart.

> Without going into too many spoilers check.

From Fantastic Fiction:

> The year: 2032 A.D. The Gloria Mundi, a starship built and manned by the new United States of Europe, touches down on the planet, Alatair Five. Disaster strikes, leaving only one apparent survivor--Paul Marlow, whose adventures in the lair of a strange primeval race known as the Bayani leads him first to their God, the omnipotent and omniscient Oruri, and eventually to an unlimited power that is so great that it must include a built-in death sentence. The forces that have remained static for centuries overcome both the forces of the future and the quest for unlimited knowledge.

[image: Cover1]

[image: Cover2]

Comment: "thanks to user who quoted "A Far Sunset". That is the answer I was looking for. Actually, this is more than correct, since I want to read all of the Edmund Cooper short stories that I read all those years ago. I'm a happy bunny today!"   @JohnTaylorHK. Glad I could help with the answer on this. Good luck in getting your accounts merged.